# Ignore a directory under `src` from compilation for a gradle project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradlew

In my project I want to add a directory under `src/main/kotlin` for experiments.
I want this directory to be ignored by gradlew compile and build targets and only want this directory to be read by the gradle when I mark some mode as experiments.
So that even if there is dirty code in experiments folder it doesn't affect the main code.
My project structure is something like this

```
  project-name
     - backend
       - src
        - main
         - kotlin
          - code
          - experiments(new dir to write some experimentation code)
```

I added the exclude statements to the `compileKotlin` and `compileTestKotlin` targets.
But still it gives the compilation and other warnings for the experiments folder.

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    exclude("**/experiments/**")
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    exclude("**/experiments/**")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting an uphill battle getting Gradle to regard a compilation as having a different set of files to your IDE.

Better just to set up a new compilation entirely.

For this, write:

```
kotlin {
    target.compilations {
        create("sandbox") {
            associateWith(getByName(KotlinCompilation.MAIN_COMPILATION_NAME))
        }
    }
}
```

And write your code in the default source directory for that compilation, `src/sandbox/kotlin`.